# No module named _ssl

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I have created a Google app engine app which searches tweets for a specific query and stores in the GAE datastore.

To connect to twitter I am using [twitter/sixohsix python library](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter). When I tried to run the app I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named _ssl
INFO     2013-11-10 09:09:37,112 server.py:561] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I don't understand whether the problem is with the twitter library or with GAE sockets!

Note: when i type `import ssl` in python idle, it works fine i.e. it is able to import the module.

Comment: Is this error occurring in the dev (SDK) environment or in production?

Comment: yes, it is occurring in dev(SDK) environment

Comment: You haven't said what OS you are running and if you have an SSL enabled version of python installed.  If you don't then you would get such an error and it has nothing to do with the 3rd party libs.  How about confirming that your python install can do SSL .  Run a simple version of the code in the default interpreter outside of appengine.  Also when you start the SDK dev server it usually complains in the log output if SSL is not available in your python runtime.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using windows 7, python 2.7.3 and GAE version 1.7.7. Yes I did try to run the code simply with python and was able to retrieve tweets from the stream. But with GAE I am getting _ssl error.

Comment: You should always use the current SDK.

Comment: Are you running the SDK from the commandline or using the launcher.  Is the python you are using for you local check the same python that you are using for the launcher ?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The problem was with the older version of SDK. Now I am using the latest version (1.8.7) and everything is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

If the library works on the production server but not on the development server, then it's most likely a bug with the SDK as it is not emulating the production setup properly.

There is an (accepted) issue just like yours already in the bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9246&q=_ssl&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log .

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right! The code works fine with the latest version of SDK.